# How do I prove $z\Delta(z+1) = \Delta(z)$, where $\Gamma(z)=1/\Delta(z)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function

EDIT notes: Deleted irrelevant information

I'm asked to prove that $z\Delta(z+1)=\Delta(z)$, where $\Delta(z)\equiv ze^{\gamma z}\prod\limits_{m=1}^\infty(1+z/m)e^{-z/m}$ and $\gamma =\lim_{n\to\infty} 1+ 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/n-\log n$.

My idea was to look at finite n both in $\gamma$ and in the product. First I assumed the theorem to be true, thus getting $\Delta(z+1)=\Delta(z)/z$. I divided both sides by $e^{\gamma z}$ and then took the logarithm. From here, managed to prove equivalence. Is there another, "cleaner" proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the telescoping sum
$$\sum_{m=1}^n \left(\log\left(1+\frac{z}{m+1}\right)-\log\left(1+\frac{z}{m}\right)\right) = \log\left(1+\frac{z}{n+1}\right) - \log(1+z)$$
Then 
$$- \log(1+z) =
 \sum_{m=1}^\infty \left(\log\left(1+\frac{z}{m+1}\right)-\log\left(1+\frac{z}{m}\right)\right) =
\sum_{m=1}^\infty \left(\log\left(\frac{z+m+1}{z+m}\right)-\log\left(\frac{m+1}{m}\right)\right) = 
\sum_{m=1}^\infty \left(\log\left(\frac{z+m+1}{z+m}\right)-\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{m}-\log\left(\frac{m+1}{m}\right)\right)
= 
\sum_{m=1}^\infty \left(\log\left(\frac{1+(z+1)/m}{1+z/m}\right)-\frac{1}{m}\right)+\gamma$$
Apply exponential to get
$$\frac{1}{1+z} = e^\gamma \prod_{m=1}^\infty\frac{1+(z+1)/m}{1+z/m}e^{-1/m}=\frac{e^{\gamma(z+1)}}{e^{\gamma z}}\prod_{m=1}^\infty \frac{(1+(z+1)/m)e^{-(z+1)/m}}{(1+z/m)e^{-z/m}}$$
Then
$$z e^{\gamma z} \prod_{m=1}^\infty (1+z/m)e^{-z/m} = z(z+1) e^{\gamma(z+1)}\prod_{m=1}^\infty (1+(z+1)/m)e^{-(z+1)/m}$$ 
and we are done

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)
Unfortunately, monday will be the earliest I can take a close look at it.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is a clean/neat proof!

Comment: How does $1/m -\log[(m+1)/m]$ give $\gamma$? I get $1+1/2+...+1/n - (\log(2/1)+\log(3/2)+...+\log[(n+1)/n])=1+1/2+...+1/n-\log(n+1)$ which is almost equal to $\gamma$. I can only think of something like $\log(n+1)/\log(n)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$

Comment: $1+1/2+...+1/n - \log(n+1) = 1+1/2+...+1/n -\log(n) + \log(n) - \log(n+1)$
But $\log(n)-\log(n+1) = \log(n/(n+1)) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$

Comment: Thank you  * character filling *

Comment: I meant $\to 1$ in my comment. I cannot edit that anymore